# ¿Cómo agrego un mensaje en un web panel que tenga botones ? Genexus

Tags: genexus

Tengo un web panel donde el usuario puede modificar sus datos cuando hace click en un botón.
Dicho botón hace su funcionalidad pero nose como agregarle un mensaje que diga "Datos actualizados correctamente"

```
Event 'Actualizar'
UpdatePersonas.Call()
Endevent
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función [msg()](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31635,Msg%20function).

```
Event 'Actualizar'
    UpdatePersonas.Call()
    MSG("Datos actualizados correctamente")
Endevent
```

Answer (score 0):

O puedes descargarte el userControl Hugao message, que tiene un mejor estilo. Y el mensaje lo manda como ventana independiente.
https://hugao1118.blogspot.com/2018/04/genexus-hugaomessages-user-control.html